# Record video frame by frame in OpenCV and ROS

Tags: c++, opencv, video, frequency, ros

I have a heavy program that I receive a message of ROS(an image) in a callback and I process it. I'd like to run the program frame per frame because I don't want to lose no frames and I'd like to save in a Video file with a certain frequency. Can anyone help me?

Comment: With that spec and no code, I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your problem exactly is. If it's just about storing the processed images you can save them with the OpenCV [cv::imwrite](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#imwrite). The other option is to use the [VideoWriter](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter) to encode the images in a video file. There you can specify the frames per second and the encoding as shown in the example.

Cheers